# Omit fields when printing Protobuf message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to choose what fields or at least what field types to be considered when calling `message.DebugString()` in Google Protobuf?

I have the following message description:

```
message Message
{
    optional string name = 1
    optional int32 blockSize = 2;
    optional bytes block = 3;
}
```

I only want to print `name` and `blockSize` and omit the `block` field, which happens to be large (e.g.: 64KB) and its content is insignificant.

I built a method that specifically adds to a `std::stringstream` only the fields of interest but it seems that I have to modify the method for every change in message description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to make a copy of the message, clear `block` from the copy, then print it.

```
Message copy = original;
copy.clear_block();
cout << copy.DebugString() << endl;
```

Note that there's no performance concern here because `DebugString()` itself is already *much* slower than making a copy of the message.

If you want to make this more general, you could write some code based on [protobuf reflection](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection) which walks over the copied message and removes all fields of type `bytes` with long sizes.

Comment: I think this is the best method to do this. As an additional question: is it even recommended to communicate with messages containing large `bytes` fields inside (e.g.: 10MB)? If I communicate through sockets, shouldn't I just send the binary block immediately after the message?

Comment: @AlexandruIrimiea - As a rule of thumb I'd say that you should not encode a protobuf larger than 1MB. Your options are either to send several messages each containing a small piece of the payload, or to place the payload after the message as you say. Note that I've seen people encode protobufs up to 2GB and get away with it, but the library really isn't designed to be used that way.